# set value array in all inputs with same tag class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, input

I'm trying to do loop over all tag with same `className` and get their value:

```
var quantity = [];
$(".add_more_items").each(function(){
    quantity.push($(this).val());
});
```

this is a result, for example:

```
['1', '9', '1']
```

but my problem is I'm trying to set value from this array to other input with same class:

```
$.each(quantity, function(index, val){
    $(".items_final").val(val);
});
```

but always set in all inputs last value from my array, i don´t know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an index assuming there is 1 to 1 mapping between the fields

```
const $final = $(".items_final");
$(".add_more_items").each(function(i, item) {
  $final[i].value = item.value; // or $final.eq(i).val(item.value)
});
```

```js
const $final = $(".items_final");
$(".add_more_items").each(function(i, item) {
  $final[i].value = item.value; // or $final.eq(i).val(item.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Add more</h3>
<input type="text" value="1" class="add_more_items" />
<input type="text" value="2" class="add_more_items" />
<input type="text" value="3" class="add_more_items" />
<input type="text" value="4" class="add_more_items" />
<hr/>
<h3>final</h3>
<input type="text" value="" class="items_final" />
<input type="text" value="" class="items_final" />
<input type="text" value="" class="items_final" />
<input type="text" value="" class="items_final" />
```

Also this is useful:

```
const quantity = $(".add_more_items").map(function(){
  return this.value; // or $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Comment: When you add index on a jquery element, it changes to javascript element, thus you cannot use jquery methods on it. When you say $final[i] it is now javascript element, so .val will not be there as its a jquery method

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your response. But browser return this: $final[i].val is not a function

Comment: @scorpions78 You will have to use $final[i].value =

Comment: You are correct. Please use `[i].value` or `.eq(i).val()` - see update